# Create a new OneNote page via Code

Tags: c#, .net, api, onenote

I'm trying to create a new page in OneNote 2013 via C#.

```
            try
        {
            onenoteApp.CreateNewPage(sectionId, out pageId, NewPageStyle.npsBlankPageWithTitle);
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Every time the COMException occurs with the message "Exception of HRESULT: 0x8004200B". The errorcode means the section is read-only(hrSectionReadOnly).
I'm not able to get the section readable to add more pages or to update to content. I tried to change the security settings of the .one files but wihtout success.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem working with C# and OneNote. Everytime I was calling a "write"-method, meaning that I wanted to edit something in a OneNote-File, I got the Exception of HRESULT: 0x8004200B.

I was using the Microsoft OneNote 12.0 type Library as Reference. I tried to use the 14.0 type Library as well, but on every method the complier said something like

> Error 1   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application' does not contain a definition for 'GetHierarchy' and no extension method 'GetHierarchy' accepting a first argument of type ...

So the solution for me was using the OneNote 14.0 type Library **AND set the Embed Interop Types to FALSE**. You can find it by clicking on the OneNote Reference (when you already added it) down in the proberties.

Since then, everything worked fine!